# How to logout the application when ethernet cable plugged out from system?

Tags: java, session, servlets, richfaces, servlet-filters

I am using Apache Tomcat server for application deployment.
Consider that I have been login to application and suddenly I was removed the Ethernet Cable from system,after this if I click application it throws 404 page not found error, this scenario no problem .In my case after removing the Ethernet Cable I will not click any where in the browser,at some time i will connect Ethernet Cable again to the system.Now if I click the application which deployed will work correctly.

I need to disconnect the session connection and need to navigate to home page when Ethernet cable Dis-connected.

`**Is't possible**` ????

Comment: try something in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is not common in web applications. But if you like to do it you can use some java script methods like this:

```
window.addEventListener('online',  updateIndicator);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateIndicator);
```

And in your javascript method you can do anyone you need to logout for example you can delete something from session:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('itemName');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to detect when your system goes offline and erase anything that connects your browser to the server.

Basically you will have to delete either the session id cookie or something from the session storage. This depends on how you have implemented your login. You could use something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('offline', disconnectSession);
function disconnectSession(){
    // remove cookie - tomcat's session cookie is JSESSIONID
    document.cookie = 'JSESSIONID=; Max-Age=0'

    // remove value from session storage
    sessionStorage.removeItem('key');
}
```